# Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml];

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, tomcat

Не разворачивает на localhost проект, переустановлена idea на версию 16, до этого все работало, может кто сталкивался... буду очень признателен за помощь!

Ошибка. На Jetty все так же... Советуют удалить steve.sh, но я его у себя не нашел.

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!-- Web -->
    <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/view/error/errorpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="club.psvm.testfordeletetwo.mvc" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

artifact

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вывод ошибки

```html
"C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2016-06-07 10:07:16,385] Artifact TestForDeleteTwo:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Soften\.IntelliJIdea2016.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TestForDeleteTwo_2"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.35
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          May 11 2016 21:57:08 UTC
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.35.0
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-b14
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Soften\.IntelliJIdea2016.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TestForDeleteTwo_2
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Soften\.IntelliJIdea2016.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TestForDeleteTwo_2\conf\logging.properties
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\endorsed
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Soften\.IntelliJIdea2016.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TestForDeleteTwo_2
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\temp
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.7 using APR version 1.5.2.
07-Jun-2016 22:07:17.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
07-Jun-2016 22:07:18.845 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016)
07-Jun-2016 22:07:19.105 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
07-Jun-2016 22:07:19.128 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
07-Jun-2016 22:07:19.131 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2074 ms
07-Jun-2016 22:07:19.186 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
07-Jun-2016 22:07:19.186 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.35
07-Jun-2016 22:07:19.207 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
07-Jun-2016 22:07:19.224 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
07-Jun-2016 22:07:19.230 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 97 ms
Connected to server
[2016-06-07 10:07:19,531] Artifact TestForDeleteTwo:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
07-Jun-2016 22:07:22.067 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
07-Jun-2016 22:07:22.181 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
07-Jun-2016 22:07:22.443 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jun 07 22:07:22 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
07-Jun-2016 22:07:22.542 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]
07-Jun-2016 22:07:36.410 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/xs/opti/SchemaDOM
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4813)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
 at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
 at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
 at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
 at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
 at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
 at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
 at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
 at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/xs/opti/SchemaDOM
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.startDocument(SchemaDOMParser.java:118)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:546)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(XMLVersionDetector.java:175)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:603)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2171)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:569)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:613)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2446)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1767)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:740)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:614)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3135)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
 ... 58 more

07-Jun-2016 22:07:36.418 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
07-Jun-2016 22:07:36.420 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
07-Jun-2016 22:07:36.435 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jun 07 22:07:22 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
07-Jun-2016 22:07:36.442 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jun 07 22:07:22 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:415)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4860)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5495)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
 at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
 at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
 at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
 at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
 at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
 at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
 at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
 at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

07-Jun-2016 22:07:36.411 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\webapps\docs
[2016-06-07 10:07:36,563] Artifact TestForDeleteTwo:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
07-Jun-2016 22:07:36.700 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\webapps\docs has finished in 288 ms
07-Jun-2016 22:07:36.701 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\webapps\examples
07-Jun-2016 22:07:37.152 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\webapps\examples has finished in 451 ms
07-Jun-2016 22:07:37.153 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\webapps\host-manager
```

application-context.xml

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="
 club.psvm.testfordeletetwo.mvc"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Логика поражает воображение. У вас приложение валится на файле `application-context.xml` и запостили все кроме него. :)

Comment: Чтобы заодно и во "всём" ошибки исправили.

Comment: Покажите `application-context.xml` и полный текст ошибки со стектрейсом (не картинкой).

Comment: да, извините, забыл….

'<context:annotation-config/>
       <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="
 club.psvm.testfordeletetwo.mvc"/>
</beans>'